# Debugging Wordpress with Netbeans & XDebug

Tags: wordpress, netbeans, xdebug

I'm trying to debug a Wordpress site with Netbeans using XDebug. I can get it to hit a breakpoint on the index.php page, but it won't break on any other page. Has anyone else run into this issue?

If I debug a concrete5 site or something it works beautifully. So it has to be something with how Wordpress works.

Comment: I happen to have all of these installed, but I don't feel like just messing around. Could you please point to specific lines/files? Or do you really mean _any_ any page.

Comment: I mean any file besides the index.php page. If I set a breakpoint on the index.php page I can then step through all of the included pages. But if I put a breakpoint in any other file it won't stop at it. Even for code that I know is definitely being run.

Comment: have you tried adding the breakpoint after the debug session started ?

Comment: Yes I've tried that. Still doesn't work. I can set a breakpoint on the /index.php file and it'll break there. If I set a breakpoint on anything else, it'll fail.

Answer (score 4):

yep.  Case-sensitive paths, softlinks, and include paths are the root of the problem.  They need to match in your IDE and your webserver. see http://www.noodlecake.com/?p=105

Comment: Stupid upvote button only works once.  *click* *click* *click*

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  I made sure I had these 2 lines in my php.ini file.

zend_extension=
xdebug.remote_enable=true

Make sure the Xdebug version is compatible with your version of PHP.

Also, check the debug port used for Xdebug. I have my defaulted to 9000

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely possible to use xDebug with WordPress. Take a look at this writeup: http://mondaybynoon.com/2011/03/28/wordpress-development-xdebug/

Answer (score 0):

I've tryed with eclipse and netbeans na dboth can't debug the wordpress's themes or plugin. They only debug the "core" of wordpress.
The only one that can debug your plugin and theme is Nusphere phpEd.
Sadly isn't free.

Comment: Yeah that's kinda my conclusion. If NuSphere was that much better I would consider buying it, but it's not worth it for debugging. Though who knows, maybe it'll drive me crazy enough one day.